# Is there any way to return the REFERRER in Yii's module/controller/action form?

Tags: php, browser, yii

I use:

```
if(!empty(YII::app()->request->urlReferrer))echo YII::app()->request->urlReferrer;
```

But, I would like to use the value of `YII::app()->request->urlReferrer` with `CHtml::link(...)` and create a link tag;

I dont want to write a:

```
<a href="<?php echo YII::app()->request->urlReferrer; ?>">Go Back</a>
```

I would like to extract the module, controller, action from the REFERRAL.

I began to think and write the plan, and i found out that i need to store the original module/controller/action on some of my webpages; If a user should navigate somewhere, some of those pages will use the stored data, like module/controller/action and current page if available, and how many items per page were listed, if available;

So, i also need a way to store the entire webpage original state, and if a user wants to come back to the original page, i have to load the data stored;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
echo CHtml::link(
        'Go Back',
        empty(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer)?'#':Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer
);
```

Comment: instead `#` may use `javascript:history.go(-1);`

Comment: @sergey yes of course. but my answer is actually incomplete atm without the extraction of the module, controller, action.

Comment: i know this, but it is not really helpfull, see new content